# How to align icon to the right and text to the left in the App Bar?

Tags: android

I am trying to display two icons to the right of my App Bar, I figured the way to place the very right icon to the right of the app bar, sadly i can only place the other icon next to the text (which means it it either placed to the very right with the text to the very right or to the very left with the title to the very left.

I want the page title to the left (as it is by default) and the `search`-icon as well as the `settings`-button to the right next to each other.

I also tried setting the `width` of my `LinearLayout` to `match_parent` instead of `wrap content`, yet that causes the `ImageButton` to be out of the bounds of the window (and not getting displayed because of that). Setting the `margin` causes the same effect. I could also not move the `ImageButton` into the `LinearLayout`, since that causes the same problem as changing the `width` of the `LinearLayout`.

What it looks like (actually):

[image]

This is almost fine, except for the text that I wish to be oriented to the start instead of the end. I'd like to avoid setting specific `dp` as width, since this will cause problems on different devices right?

**My code**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                >

                <SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_search"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:maxWidth="1000000dp" />

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_settings_button"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_icon_foreground"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You'll get everything you want for free if you use a menu with a SearchView and a normal action Button and a Toolbar without any extra settings for gravity etc. See this [guide on action views](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/action-views.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

I do that with `ImageView` so just replace with `TextView`. As for the icons you need to create a menu resource file and inflate it like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate( R.menu.your_menu, menu );

    return true;
}
```

Then:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        //...
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Example resource menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` like below:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right">
                <SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_search"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toolbar_settings_button"/>
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_settings_button"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_icon_foreground"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the LinearLayout to RelativeLayout and align the views to the end... Change your code like this:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            >
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/toolbar_settings_button"/>


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_settings_button"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_icon_foreground"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```